# Which websites should a system administrator read?

Tags: untagged

I try to religiously follow [planet sysadmin](http://planetsysadmin.com/) as well as [IBM developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/).

Which ones do you read and advise to other system administrators?

Comment: +1 Excellent question.  I've just gone through and dropped almost all of the sites below into my Google Reader.  I love Google Reader -- subscribing is almost trivially easy, I can read it from almost anwhere (including my blackberry), and if the feed is too busy/boring/annoying/whatever, unsubscribing is just as easy.  Joy!

Comment: I personnally prefer running my own instance of Tiny Tiny RSS. (http://tt-rss.org/trac/). It's free software, fast, very similar to reader in terms of features , and saves me from disclosing any more information to google. I have actually now come to prefer tt-rss overtime and would not switch back to reader.

Answer (score 28):

Since every modern System Administrator should be using a feed reader, here's my selections from Google Reader [NOTE: These are RSS feeds, not the standard viewable sites themselves!]:

System Administration and Storage:

- **Boiling Linux and Windows -** http://feeds.feedburner.com/BoilingLinuxAndWindows
- **Everything Sysadmin -** http://www.everythingsysadmin.com/atom.xml
- **High Scalability - Building bigger, faster, more reliable websites. -** http://highscalability.com/rss.xml
- **Kevin Closson's Oracle Blog: Platform, Storage & Clustering Topics -** http://kevinclosson.wordpress.com/feed/
- **Last In - First Out -** http://lastinfirstout.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default
- **Observations from a Tech Architect: Enterprise Implementation Issues -** http://rss.ittoolbox.com/rss/eai-implementation.xml
- **Services for UNIX - Interoperability -** http://blogs.msdn.com/sfu/atom.xml
- **Standalone Sysadmin -** [http://feeds.feedburner.com/standalone-sysadmin/rWoU](http://standalone-sysadmin.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default)
- **StorageMojo -** http://storagemojo.com/?feed=rss
- **The Lone Sysadmin -** http://feeds.feedburner.com/lonesysadmin/mkpe
- **Planet CentOS -** http://planet.centos.org/atom.xml

Security:

- **Red Hat Errata -** https://rhn.redhat.com/rpc/recent-errata.pxt
- **Debian Security -** http://www.debian.org/security/dsa-long
- **Schneier on Security -** http://www.schneier.com/blog/index.rdf

Tech/IT News:

- **Techdirt -** http://feeds.techdirt.com/techdirt/feed
- **LWN.net -** http://lwn.net/headlines/newrss
- **Slashdot Firehose Stories -** http://slashdot.org/firehose_stories.rss
- **TechCrunch -** http://feedproxy.google.com/TechCrunch

Others that are important and popular among sysadmins:

- **Cool Tools -** http://feeds.feedburner.com/CoolTools
- **xkcd.com -** http://xkcd.com/rss.xml
- **ThinkGeek :: What's New -** http://www.thinkgeek.com/thinkgeek.rss
- **The Daily WTF -** http://syndication.thedailywtf.com/TheDailyWtf
- **Official Gmail Blog -** http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/atom.xml
- **The official update feed from the Google Apps team -** http://feeds.feedburner.com/GoogleAppsUpdates
- **What Would Tyler Durden Do -** http://www.wwtdd.com/feed/atom/

Comment: How did you get the login to my google reader account? +1 for everything. I'd give you a bonus for listing my blog (Standalone Sysadmin), but I can only give one :-)

Comment: techcrunch alone makes it impossible to follow all of them.

Comment: Yeah, honestly, I don't read every post from techcrunch.  I just skim through it every few days and then read any entries where the title jumps out at me.  I probably only read about 5%-10% of it.  But, there's still some good stuff on there! ;-)

Comment: Wonder how many people knew what a great sysadmin site WWTDD.com is...

Comment: I specifically listed it both last and among other sites that are not necessarily sysadmin specific or related, but that (in my experience) most sysadmins tend to enjoy.

Answer (score 21):

I'm subscribed to the following in my feed reader:

- [The Blog of Ben Rockwood](http://www.cuddletech.com/blog/) - excellent Solaris blog
- [Commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com) - subscribe to one of the 3 or 10 vote feeds for useful command line tips.
- [Unix admin corner](http://uadmin.blogspot.com/)
- [Sun Bigadmin updated feed](http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/content/rss/recently_updated.xml) - occasionally has some useful links, but there is a lot of noise
- [Daily Vim](http://dailyvim.blogspot.com/) - Learn your editor and learn it well

There are a few others I have in my sysadmin category, but they may not be generally applicable. I'd also suggest reading a lot of sites that would be considered 'sites programmers should read' - hacker news, programming.reddit etc., but then I tend to have an interest in both programming and systems administration.

Comment: Seconded for Ben Rockwoods blog. That guy knows his stuff and actually walks the walk, rather than flapping his gums. I wish he would post more often

Comment: Speaking of which; I wish he would produce some more SA Pro podcasts.

Answer (score 12):

On a regular basis?  **None.**

In the end, most sites just end up being a time suck (like Server Fault?)

Comment: So true. I search the net if I have a specific issue, but I don't regularly read websites. Most just clutter my brain with stuff that is not quite applicable to my job.

Comment: It's good to stay on top of things, though. I think a good sysadmin stays on top of happenings in their field of work. But the HUGE list above is ridiculous. I have 3 sites on my RSS reader (Slashdot, LWN.net and Wired) and I don't have time to keep up with all the discussion.

Answer (score 7):

For some light reading you can't beat [BOFH](http://www.theregister.co.uk/odds/bofh/) ;->

Answer (score 5):

Why [slashdot.org](http://slashdot.org) of course!

Answer (score 5):

For when you just need to know that you're not the only one...

http://www.thedailywtf.com

Answer (score 4):

No one has mentioned Microsoft's [Sysinternals Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/sysinternals/), which has the best advanced Windows troubleshooting information anywhere.

Comment: The forums are very good, too.

Answer (score 3):

I read Hacker News. The name is misleading, as it rarely has any hacker news, but very informative stories on every tech-subject imaginable.

http://news.ycombinator.com/

Answer (score 2):

Of course [this site](https://serverfault.com/) !!!

Ok ! I'm leaving =====>[]

Answer (score 2):

If you are linux-y: http://freshmeat.net (turn up the odd free software gem)

If you work in a school: http://edugeek.net

If you want to be secure: http://isc.sans.org

Answer (score 2):

The [BOFH](http://www.theregister.co.uk/odds/bofh/)!!

Answer (score 2):

I have gazillions of technology and vendor specific feeds in my RSS reader. Too many, perhaps.

Those that haven't yet been mentioned and are relatively generic:

[Datacenter Knowledge](http://www.datacenterknowledge.com/) and [Royal Pingdom](http://royal.pingdom.com/) often prove an interesting outlook about what's going on.

Not strictly websites, the [NANOG](http://rss.gmane.org/topics/complete/gmane.org.operators.nanog) and [Outages](http://rss.gmane.org/topics/complete/gmane.org.operators.isotf.outages) lists can be helpful weather reports.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend Ars Technica in general, but a daily digest of the Server Room forum on their site is just awesome:

http://episteme.arstechnica.com/eve/forums/a/frm/f/833003030931

Just tons of great info, especially on VMWare etc.

Answer (score 2):

I subscribe to several of the [planet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_(software)) aggregators.

- planet sysadmin - http://planetsysadmin.com/
- planet sysadmin - http://www.sysadminblogs.com/planet/
- planet security - http://planetsecurity.bacarospo.net/
- planet Ubuntu- http://planet.ubuntu.com/
- planet Debian - http://planet.debian.org/
- planet network management - http://planetnetworkmanagement.com/

Answer (score 1):

My regularly read sysadmin related RSS feeds, excluding those listed above:

- [Linux Weekly News](http://lwn.net/headlines/newrss)
- [Out-Law UK IT Law news](http://www.out-law.com/feeds/out-law_roundup.aspx)
- [Bruce Schneier's Cryptogram](http://www.schneier.com/crypto-gram-rss.xml)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep an eye on security issues you can check out:

[SANS Dshield](http://www.dshield.org/indexd.html)

[Darkreading](http://www.darkreading.com/)

[Websense Security Labs](http://securitylabs.websense.com/)

[McAfee's TrustedSource](http://www.trustedsource.org/en/home)

[US Computer Emergency Readiness Team Vulnerabilities Listing](http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls)

Answer (score 1):

[HackADay](http://www.hackaday.com) is one of my favorites! It is good for killing time at work.

Answer (score 0):

The "Serious Hardware/Software Crap" and related forums at [Something Awful](http://forums.somethingawful.com) I've found to be a source of solid advice, both for sysadmin and coding questions.

Answer (score 0):

[The Joyeur blog, by Joyent.](http://www.joyeur.com/) Sadly they don't seem to be posting much content these days. Are they even doing the podcast anymore ?

Answer (score 0):

[asktheadmin.com](http://www.asktheadmin.com/) always has good content.  [petri.co.il](http://www.petri.co.il/) also has some awesome Windows articles and a large and active forum.

Comment: petri has been a great help for years

Answer (score 0):

I've cut back on my RSS reader dramatically. Mostly it's web comics, which is about 8 or 10 sites now.

I try to follow high quality content sources and interesting people on Twitter. Most of the blog authors I had in RSS are on Twitter and link their latest post. A lot of colleagues, friends and acquaintances I know in [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) and Web Operations are on Twitter, and post links to blog posts, news articles and other sites I find valuable and interesting.

It's like getting a "best of" without having to sift through all the crap. Other people did it for me. It's the ultimate in laziness.

Answer (score 0):

I usually visist [OSNews](http://osnews.com) to see whats going on in the OS world (allthough it's a bit Linux-aimed)

Answer (score 0):

I try to visit [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/), [Sinfest](http://www.sinfest.net/), [Something Positive](http://www.somethingpositive.net/) and [Questionable Content](http://questionablecontent.net/) daily.

Answer (score 0):

For getting a grip on the technology, digital life, and political zeitgeist, you might try [popurls](http://popurls.com). The site is nicely designed and gives a reasonable way outside of a feed reader to grab quick look at the state of things. The advantage over a feed reader is that there is less of an urge to "deal" with everything and get it out of your "inbox" because there is no "inbox."